# KAFKA CONNECT ETL Data from SQLSERVER to SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using docker-compose do start sql server, zookeeper, kafka, schema-registry, kafka-connect. I need to extract data from a table in SQL SERVER and transport to another SQL SERVER. Can someone check if my enviroment is right?

```
sql-cdc-kafka-connect-1    | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic sqlserver.dbo.t1 to Avro:
sql-cdc-kafka-connect-1    | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

**My Source Connector**

```
{
   "name":"db-connector",
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",    
      "database.server.name":"sqlserver",
      "database.hostname":"sqlserver",
      "database.port":"1433",
      "database.user":"sa",
      "database.password":"P@ssw0rd",
      "database.dbname":"db",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"kafka:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic":"schema-changes.db"
   }
}
```

**My Destination Connector**

```
{
   "name":"jdbc-sqlserver-sink",
   "config":{
      "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
      "tasks.max":"1",
      "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
      "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
      "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
      "header.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter",
      "topics":"sqlserver.dbo.t1",      
      "connection.url":"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=instanceName;databaseName=db",
      "connection.user":"kafka",
      "connection.password":"kafka",
      "insert.mode":"upsert",
      "pk.mode":"record_key",
      "auto.create":"true",
      "auto.evolve":"false",
      "max.retries":"1",
      "delete.enabled":"true",
      "transforms":"dropPrefix,unwrap",
      "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
      "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"sqlserver.dbo.(.*)",
      "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1",
      "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
      "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false"
   }
}
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include it, not use comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates your data is not Avro. Double check your key and value converter settings match in both connectors since you've not shared what they are in the Debezium config

Also, when using Docker compose, you cannot use localhost as connection strings to be able to reach external systems/containers.